# OrientDB - How to append a string with SQL

Tags: sql, orientdb

I am trying to update a string with another string using SQL.

```
UPDATE #9:14 set foo = (SELECT foo.append('abc')FROM #9:14)
```

returns: 
['123abc']

This does what I want with the exception that it wraps the string in brackets. Is there a better solution?

Comment: If you don't want the brackets try with: select from #9:14 unwind foo. Hope it helps. Let me know.

Comment: HI Michela, thank you for the suggestion. I am still not able to get unwind to work on my update. Using the sql command UPDATE #9:14 set foo = (SELECT foo.append('abc')FROM #9:14 UNWIND foo) does not remove the brackets from the update. UNWIND is working on collections when I perform a normal query, but the sql code I am using still contains the brackets. Am I using UNWIND correctly?

Comment: Hi, after you've done the update command, if you do a SELECT foo FROM #9:14 UNWIND foo, the brackets will "disappeared" but, only from the graphically point of view not physically. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Unfortunately I am stuck. I am performing multiple updates on a single field. Each update wraps in multiple brackets. Unwinding will only remove one set of brackets. And I need to have this done at the database level.