# OrientDB update a field with an addition to the already existing string

Tags: sql, orientdb

I have a vertex that contains a string. I would like to update this string by adding a string to the end. The outcome should be the original string + the new string. I thought I could do this with append but it keeps making an embedded set. The code below returns ['123abc'] instead of '123abc'

I've posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665658/orientdb-how-to-append-a-string-with-sql), but did not find a remedy. This seems like a simple sql command but I do not know the code. Please note I have also tried using unwind but it did not work. Thank you.

```
CREATE VERTEX V SET foo = '123'
UPDATE V SET foo = (SELECT foo.append('abc')FROM(SELECT FROM V WHERE foo = '1'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using 
`UPDATE V SET foo = foo.append('abc') where foo = '123'`

Comment: Eureka. You just made my day. Thank you so much.